# Text file php retrieve

Tags: php

Imagine I have a certain text file like this:-

`52 apple, one and teen, 682`

How to do I take them like this?

```
$a['aa']['a1'] - 52
$a['aa']['a2'] - apple
$a['bb']['b1'] - one
$a['bb']['b2'] - and
$a['bb']['b3'] - teen
$a['cc']['c1'] - 682
```

Answer (score 0):

This reads lines from a file, splits them by comma+space and splits each of those by a space:

```
<?php

$lines = file($filename);

$foo = array_map(
    function($v) {
        return array_map(
            function($u) {
                return explode(" ", $u);
            },
            explode(", ", trim($v))
        );
    },
    $lines
);

var_dump($foo);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "52"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "apple"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "one"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "and"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "teen"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "682"
    }
  }
}
```

If you really need specific indices you could handle those in the anonymous functions for each `array_map` on your own. Right now they're just numerically indexed.

Comment: WOW .., You are very fast :D Thx Bro :) @ccKep

Comment: @penchY  what about indexes ['aa']['a1'] ...?

Comment: WARNING array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array on line number 13
NULL

Comment: I have no idea what line #13 (or 12) is for you, [here](https://3v4l.org/QRAJP)'s a link to 3v4l.org testing the code.

Comment: [link](https://3v4l.org/SLFks) how to get only 'apple' ? error: `Array to string conversion in /in/SLFks on line 22 Array`

Comment: `$foo[0][0][1]`, it's `$foo[line_number_in_file][index_from_comma_separation][index_from_space_separation]`.